# Can we run 32bit Programs on Alpine Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, 32bit, alpine-linux

I recently installed a jenkins using docker using the official image from blueocean. It is based on alpine linux.

Now I cant run 32bit programs on it

```
 $ /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.3/aapt
 bash: /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.3/aapt: No such file or 
 directory
```

And I can't find out which packages need to be installed for running 32 bit programs. Could It be possible that the official blueoceans (jenkins) image does not support running 32bit programs when it is impossible to build many things without it.

Also, I found out [this issue](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/169) 
which says

> "it doesn't seem that it is possible to build android currently on alpine"

But can't wrap my head around it. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: What does `ldd /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/25.0.3/aapt` say? Also try to use `strace` to understand what is happening.  Have you installed some 32 bits variant of essential runtime shared libraries (e.g. `libc6-i386`)

Comment: I cannot find libc6-i386 alternate for alpine linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

musl (and therefore Alpine) doesn't really support "multilib" like glibc.  You need to have a 32-bit environment in a chroot to run 32-bit applications.  Follow the [chroot install guide](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Installing_Alpine_Linux_in_a_chroot) on the wiki, and make sure to pass `--arch x86` to each `apk` command; this will give you a 32-bit chroot on which you can run 32-bit applications.

As for running Android development tools on Alpine: I started a library called [gcompat](https://code.foxkit.us/adelie/gcompat) that attempts to allow glibc binaries to run natively on musl without using glibc.  There are [a few outstanding issues](https://bts.adelielinux.org/buglist.cgi?product=gcompat&component=Library&resolution=---) left before it can run the Android tools, but more testing is always welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I installed iSH on my iPhone which is running: alpine Linux I-386 or -> musl-i386 and i would like try to chroot into a debian based distribution  (Ubuntu or Kali) and be able to use apt/apt-get. I find this might relate to the issue I have when chrooting in to Ubuntu and apt will not run at all. I’ve been using a script provided by someone online:

https://github.com/MFDGaming/Ubuntu-In-Ish/raw/master/ubuntu.sh

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.